# nginx started but port 80 isn't in use (according to netstat) on AWS

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, nginx, firewall

I am running Ubuntu server 14. I have a nginx server listening on port 80. It starts up and runs fine and I know this because it was running before. Something to do with amazon web services changed my firewall I think. The server was up and running but now when direct the browser to the public DNS or IP address of the server it responds with `this webpage is not available`. 
I ran `sudo netstat -antp` and this was the output:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      941/sshd
tcp        0      0 172.31.28.156:22        24.78.205.33:9738       ESTABLISHED 1663/sshd: ubuntu [
tcp        0    340 172.31.28.156:22        24.78.205.33:10419      ESTABLISHED 1796/sshd: ubuntu [
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      941/sshd
```

I know that there should be a port open for nginx. What is going on here? Is it a firewall issue? It's a tough problem for me because I don't even know the correct terminology for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure nginx is actually starting? What does `sudo service nginx status` give you ?

Comment: This is likely that nginx didn't start at all. What's the output of `pgrep -fl nginx` ? What's the content of your error log ?

Comment: pgrep shows that nginx is running. `service ... status` says nginx is running. I described the conents of the error log in a comment on the answer.

Comment: What gives `lsof -p $(pgrep -f nginx -d ',') -nP | egrep -i "pid|tcp"` (install lsof if necessary) ? That's not related to a firewall, that's related to the nginx process.

Comment: Thanks, the command just returns this: `COMMAND  PID     USER   FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME` I suppose those are just headers to a table.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some troubleshooting tips:

First, make sure you are root (it will save you some time)

`$ sudo su`

Then, see if nginx won't just tell you what's bothering it:

```
# service nginx status
# nginx -t
```

That ought to tell you the problem. If it doesn't, do this:

```
# service nginx start
# tail /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

and that *will*

Commonly, it is an error in a config file, but in your case, it is likely that some other service is tying up one of the ports that nginx is configured to use. Typically, that's port 80 and port 8080... so, find the service:

```
# netstat -lnp | grep -E '80|8080'
```

and act accordingly:

```
# service apache2 stop
# apt-get remove tomcat7
```

^ But, you'll have to figure those last two out on your own...

Comment: I ran the commands. Nginx is running, nginx.conf tested successfully. Running `service nginx start` didn't give any output. The most recent errors are from Nov. 20.  They all have the form `[error] 2293#0: *1530 open() "<path to file>"` I'm quite sure they aren't relevant. Nothing is using port 80 or port 8080. Shouldn't the `netstat` command show nginx using port 80 if things were working?